# Trying to compare a list of emails in TreasureData with a list of emails in DBeaver to find missing emails

Tags: sql, excel, compare, dbeaver, treasure-data

I have lists of emails from DBeaver and the same lists from TreasureData but with some emails missing.

My task is to compare the lists to find out which emails are missing from the corresponding list but I am not sure how to go about doing so.

I have tried copying the lists into Excel but there are multiple thousands of rows of information so I don't think that is a viable way to go about completing this task.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are several ways to do this: search for duplicates or unique values, count missing values with COUNFIT and more. There are thousands of examples here on SO. Just search a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you save as on each file only with a single email column to two text files, the below one liner should get you to the solution. You would run it twice if you wanted to see which in file 1 were missing from file 2 and which from file 2 were missing in file 1.

Replace the file names below as appropriate for Filename_1, Filename_2, and OutputFilename.

```
Filename_1="file1.csv**"; Filename_2="file1.csv"; OutputFilename="MissingFromFilename_2.csv"; for Email in `cat ${Filename_1}`; do Present=`grep -i ${Email} ${Filename_2} | wc -l`; if [[ ${Present} -eq "0" ]] ; then echo ${Email} ; fi  ; done > ${OutputFilename}
```